# Rename a column in each table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a DB with 3 tables (`Table1`, `Table2` and `Table3`). The `Table1 and 3` have a column named "MyColumn" how (if possible) rename all "MyColumn" to the new name "MyNewName" ?

In my project, it's much more table (not only 3)

Thanks,

Comment: If it's only 3 (and not 300) tables, why not issue 3 separate `ALTER TABLE` statements?

Comment: Sorry, of course it's for a lot of table, 3 in my text but much more in my project

Answer (score 1):

If you have exactly 3 tables, Why not you use 3 separate ALTER TABLE statements??

If you have more table in the same database then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' +
    t.Table_Name +
    ' Rename column ' +
c.Column_Name +
';'
FROM Information_Schema.tables t
    INNER JOIN Information_Schema.columns C
    ON t.Table_name = c.Table_name
WHERE c.Column_Name = 'MyColumn'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SP_RENAME 'TableName.[Your_Old_ColumnName]' , '[Your_New_ColumnName]', 'COLUMN'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
alter table table1,table3 mycolumn change mynewcolumn
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

ALTER TABLE Table1
  RENAME COLUMN MyColumn to MyNewName;